# Singleton implementation laziness with static constructor

Tags: c#, singleton, static-constructor

Jon Skeet suggests [in his singleton implementation](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) that if you require the maximum laziness for your [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) you should add a static constructor which will make the compiler mark the type as beforefieldinit.

However, I did some testing and it seems that it's more lazy *without* the beforefieldinit.

Code sample (the private constructor call outputs to console and verifies that the fields were initialized:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    public static string Stub()
    {
        return "123";
    }

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    //static Singleton()
    //{
    //}
    private Singleton()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("private ctor");
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

When I call Singleton.Stub() the private constructor is not being hit, and when I uncomment the static constructor, the private constructor is always called.

This is the only difference I could track made by the static constructor.

In my attempts to understand what difference will the beforefieldinit do I've also read Skeet's answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610818/what-does-beforefieldinit-flag-do) tried it with passing false to DoSomething() - with or without the static constructor the private constructor is not being called.

```
public static void DoSomething(bool which)
{
    if (which)
    {
        var a = Singleton.Stub();
    }
    else
    {
        Faketon.Stub();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the value of `which` here? Sounds like it's probably `false`.

Comment: The first code sample is not using the DoSomething() method, I simply call `Singleton.Stub()` from Main().. in the second code sample which is always false.

Comment: That's probably because you pass a constant to the `DoSomething(false)` method and you `if` statement will be optimized, so the `Singleton.Stub()` is optimzed/removed from the code.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - I tried to uncheck the optimize code from the properties window but I still get the same results.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323706/creating-tags-based-on-people-rather-than-technology-jon-skeet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I call Singleton.Stub() the private constructor is not being hit, when I uncomment the static ctor private constuctor is always called.

It's not clear what the value of `which` is here, but fundamentally you've got four cases:

- Static constructor, `Singleton.Stub` called: type initializer is guaranteed to run
- Static constructor, `Singleton.Stub` not called: type initializer is guaranteed not to run
- No static constructor, `Singleton.Stub` called: type initializer *may* run, but isn't guaranteed to
- No static constructor, `Singleton.Stub` not called: type initializer *may* run, but isn't guaranteed to

The last two cases only differ in that if you change `Singleton.Stub` to use a static field, the third case becomes "type initializer is guaranteed to run".

Comment: 1.So why you suggest (in the above quoted article) to add the static ctor for full laziness? When Stub is called without static ctor type initializer may run, with static ctor it will always run - less lazy? 2.`Singleton.Stub not called: type initializer may run, but isn't guaranteed to` - what may cause that the type initializer may run out of the blue?

Comment: @BornToCode: 1) My fully lazy version uses a static constructor in a nested type which will only be initialized if `Instance` is used. Your code doesn't have a nested type - it's not the same scenario. 2) When a method is first run, it's reasonable (but not required) for the JIT compiler to initialize all types which *might* be needed by the method, and which have lax initialization guarantees. It means it doesn't need to check each time whether the type *has* been initialized.